# Дополнительный тайтл для записи WP?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, как сделать такое, как на скрине в сайдбаре (а именно "дополнительный краткий" тайтл )?

[image]

Есть SEO-заголовок, есть длинный H1 в статье (тут пусть будет плагин Yost), и есть блок (в данном случае популярных программ), в котором "Title" краткий, т.е. скажем, название программы без "скачать бесплатно" и с всплывающей подсказкой tooltip.

Плагины, которые я ставлю для вывода похожих/последних записей, берут Title из H1 статьи полностью, а хотелось бы сделать, краткий. Может есть какие-то плагины, которые добавят "дополнительный Title ", или как его назвать. Или можно как-то через ACF сделать? Прописать доп поле для статьи, в него записать нужный "краткий дополнительный татйл" ?

Или это можно решить другим путем?